# Delete rows based on Notes and Date Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying macro to delete rows in excel based on certain conditions.

The conditions are that if the Cell in the `Notes` column (Column `H`) = `Stock` or `Custom` then delete each row that has a due date(Column `G`) after 3 days from today.

I also want to delete rows that do not contain `STOCK` OR `FABRIC` but has a due date after 2 weeks from today.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far, even if it's just a start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: If I had any code i would've included it

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows that you are iterating through can be tricky even if you know your way through VBA. The trick is that you have to start at the bottom and work you way up, otherwise you delete the row you are on, sending you immediately to the next row, and then you iterate... to your next row. So you skip rows unless you go backwards.

Your subroutine will look something like:

```
Dim deleteRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'get the last row
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row

    'iterate from the last row to the first row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1

        'test this row we are on for your first condition
        If (Sheet1.Range("H" & i).Value = "Stock" Or Sheet1.Range("H" & i).Value = "Custom") _
                And Sheet1.Range("G" & i).Value > Now() + 3 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(i).Delete
        'test for second condition
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("H" & i).Value <> "STOCK" And Sheet1.Range("H" & i).Value <> "FABRIC" _
                And Sheet1.Range("G" & i).Value > Now() + 20 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(i).Delete
        End If

    'on to the next row up
    Next i
End Sub
```

Obviously there are some tweaks you'll have to make, but that's the jist of that.

Comment: Thank you this worked with a few tweaks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification from @JNevill's solution that does not require you to go backwards. The reason this works is that the macro does not delete rows one by one, *instead*, it adds the rows-to-be-deleted to a `Union` of rows and then deletes them all at the end in **one** go.

This will be faster as well since you will only have 1 instance of deletion rather 1 instance per met criteria. How much faster depends on how many rows are going to be deleted: the more the row to delete, the greater the benefit from this method

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteMe()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, DeleteMe As Range

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("H" & i) = "Stock" Or ws.Range("H" & i) = "custom" And ws.Range("G" & i) > Now() + 3 Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("H" & i)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("H" & i))
        End If
    ElseIf ws.Range("H" & i) <> "Stock" And ws.Range("H" & i) <> "Fabric" & ws.Range("G" & i) < Now() + 14 Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("H" & i)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("H" & i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```